# Not able to share Membership Users with 2 application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a 1 running .net website which was build in v2 framework.
Recently we have created 1 section in  v4 using vs 2010. My new application is hosted under 2.0 framework. So the thing is Parent Application is on 2.0 and Child application is on 4.0 running under 2.0 with same database. Now my Membership users are not getting shared. Users created with 4.0 application is not able to login to 2.0 application and vice verse.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: You're hosting a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET application in a 2.0 App Pool?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: have you set the applicationName in the membership config for both apps? [see here](http://bit.ly/5G81US)

Comment: TIM i am not running it under 2.0 app pool. my .net 2.0 is my parent application and .net 4.0 is child. and its in 4.0 app pool

Comment: I have made the Machine code in web.config of 4.0application same as 2.0 application. Now my 2.0 user are able to login in but users created from 4.0 application is not able to login in Parent application.